# How to remove div elements within specific div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to remove all div elements with class `facebook`, `twitter`, `LinkedIn`, `googlePlus` who has parent id **show-share-count**

How to do this?

```js
$("div").remove(".facebook");
$("div").remove(".twitter");
$("div").remove(".linkedIn");
$("div").remove(".googlePlus");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="show-share-count">
  <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
  <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
  <div class="linkedIn">LinkedIn</div>
  <div class="googlePlus">Google Plus</div>
  <div class="share-count">Total Count</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
<div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
<div class="linkedIn">LinkedIn</div>
<div class="googlePlus">Google Plus</div>
<div class="share-count">Total Count</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this just only one line in script section.

```
<script>
$("#show-share-count").find(".facebook, .twitter, .linkedIn, .googlePlus").remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use following script for this

```
$('#show-share-count .facebook, #show-share-count .twitter, #show-share-count .linkedIn, #show-share-count .googlePlus, #show-share-count .share-count').remove();
```

> or you can use `.children()`..

```
$("#show-share-count").children(".facebook , .twitter , .linkedIn, .googlePlus").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this .[`children()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwim9oWH7PvTAhVKPY8KHXgFDSUQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fchildren%2F&usg=AFQjCNHPT4E4KY2m5A8FOdYqEf2zub8NYQ&sig2=hDV79b3VgC5nbgKsjmvbqg) .They will find the children element of the `show-share-count`

```js
$("#show-share-count").children(".facebook , .twitter , .linkedIn, .googlePlus").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-share-count">
  <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
  <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
  <div class="linkedIn">LinkedIn</div>
  <div class="googlePlus">Google Plus</div>
  <div class="share-count">Total Count</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
<div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
<div class="linkedIn">LinkedIn</div>
<div class="googlePlus">Google Plus</div>
<div class="share-count">Total Count</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#show-share-count").find(".facebook, .twitter, .linkedIn, .googlePlus, .share-count").remove();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5p6jbsy2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use .empty from Jquery if you want to empty the whole div

https://api.jquery.com/empty/

or

```
$("#show-share-count .facebook").remove()
```

if you want to remove a specific div

Answer (score 0):

You can use below also:

```
$('#show-share-count .facebook,.twitter,.linkedIn,.googlePlus,.share-count').remove();
```